# OpenMP based extension for Pytorch with CUDA

Tags: c++, pytorch, openmp, libtorch

I try to develop a pytorch extension with *libtorch* and *OpenMP*.
When I test my code, it goes well in CPU model and takes about 1s to finish all operations:

```py
s = time.time()
adj_matrices = batched_natural_neighbor_edges(x) # x is a tensor from torch.Tensor
print(time.time() - s)
```

Output:

```sh
1.2259256839752197
```

It seems everything goes well, and the duration is normal. But after I use `torch.to` to move the tensor to GPU and do this job again:

```py
x = x.to('cuda')
s = time.time()
adj_matrices = batched_natural_neighbor_edges(x) # x is a tensor from torch.Tensor
print(time.time() - s)
```

Output:

```sh
16.806606769561768
```

It seems that the parallel operation is not working in GPU.

My C++ extension and code of OpenMP as below, *natural_neighbor.cpp*:

```cpp
torch::Tensor cal_adj_matrix(const torch::Tensor &point_cloud, const torch::Tensor &knn_indices)
{
    int point_num = point_cloud.size(0);
    std::vector<std::set<int>> knn_idx(point_num, std::set<int>());
    std::vector<std::set<int>> reversed_knn_idx(point_num, std::set<int>());
    init_knn_and_reverse_knn(knn_indices, knn_idx, reversed_knn_idx, point_num);
    torch::Tensor adj_matrix = torch::zeros({point_num, point_num});
    std::vector<torch::Tensor> targets(point_num);
    std::vector<torch::Tensor> neighbors(point_num);
    /** 
     * here is the code for OpenMP
     **/
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for default(none) shared(point_num, knn_idx, reversed_knn_idx, adj_matrix, targets, neighbors)
    for (int i = 0; i < point_num; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> temp_neighbor_idx;
        std::set_intersection(knn_idx[i].begin(),
                              knn_idx[i].end(),
                              reversed_knn_idx[i].begin(),
                              reversed_knn_idx[i].end(),
                              std::back_inserter(temp_neighbor_idx));
        neighbors[i] = torch::tensor(temp_neighbor_idx);
        targets[i] = torch::full(neighbors[i].size(0), i);
        adj_matrix[i][i] = 1;
    }
    torch::Tensor target_idx = torch::cat(targets, -1);
    torch::Tensor neighbor_idx = torch::cat(neighbors, -1);
    adj_matrix = adj_matrix.index_put({target_idx, neighbor_idx}, torch::ones(1));
    return adj_matrix;
}
```

cpp extension *setup.py*:

```py
setup(
    # package name
    name='torch_cpp_extension',
    # module version
    version="0.1",
    # cpp file path & module names
    ext_modules=[
        CppExtension(name='natural_neighbor', sources=['src/natural_neighbor.cpp'],
                     extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'] # here is compilation flag)
    ],
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': BuildExtension
    }
)
```

Sum-up:

1. How can I use OpenMP on GPU? Is there any necessary compilation flag that I forget？
2. Is the OpenMP related macro definition correct in my code?
3. Is there any better way to accelerate `for` iteration when traverse a tensor?

My environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-90-generic x86_64)
- Compiler: I'm not sure which compiler I use. The compilation process is done with `torch.utils.cpp_extension` and I only use command `python setup.py install`. Other compiler in system is gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Comment: Is your only evidence that the code isn't running on the GPU the runtime? Could it be that the code for the GPU is just slow?

Comment: @talonmies According to this: https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2018/presentation/s8344-openmp-on-gpus-first-experiences-and-best-practices.pdf. It seems that the code for GPU should be faster with OpenMP, and it worked in GPU indeed because when I use `nvidia-smi` to see the GPU status, it was really running in GPU

Comment: I don't understand. In the question you wrote "It seems that the parallel operation is not working in GPU" but in your comment you say it was. Which is it?

Comment: @talonmies I mean the codes are working in GPU indeed, but it is serial, not parallel

Comment: That isn't possible. There is only "using GPU" or "not using GPU". If you can see the GPU being used, then the code is just slow.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your openmp basicly sends to cpu then again to gpu creating the slowdown. Double check that the integration works right.

Second option is that std operations are just slow on gpu u r std::set_intersection and I am bot sure how that's compiled for gpu. Again u could be moving things to cpu which is gona slow u down